# Can the onListViewUpdated() method run async?

Tags: javascript, spfx-extensions, listviewcommandset

I need to implement a button that is only visible if the user has edit permissions for an item in a list. Therefore I have to make an async api call in the onListViewUpdated() method, but I does not seem to work